# Hide Cash On Delivery Payment even when it is enabled

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, cash-on-delivery

I am using the defaut payment method called **Cash On Delivery Payment**.

The method is enabled and it shoud stay like that.

I want just to hide the method from the checkout page.

Where are the files for this payment method, I want to edit them and make this method simply to not appear.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

> The method is enabled and it shoud stay like that.

There is no reason to keep it enabled *in the store* if you don't show it in the frontend. If you need it enabled for backend orders, configure it as enabled in the default configuration and as disabled in the websites or store view configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Onepage Checkout you can edit:

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml and to check:

```
if ($_code == 'cashondelivery') {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Not working still displaying the method!

Comment: Are you sure that there is no theme that overwrites the base and the store is using Onepage Checkout? Please delete the content of the file and see if all of the payment methods will disappear. If not - you can enable path hints to see which template is used - admin panel -> System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Debug -> Template Path Hints : Yes (for Current Configuration Scope you must select website in order to view the option).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event `'payment_method_is_active'` and in your observer method check for payment method cash on delivery and set it inactive using the following code: `$this->resut = false;`
This will work without changing any theme's file.

Comment: Thia does not answer the question asked.